# ffmpeg split video file from some position

Tags: ffmpeg

When I used:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:03 -i c:\test1.wmv -vcodec copy -acodec copy c:\test2.wmv
```

All is OK.

But when I wrote:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:03 -i c:\test1.wmv -vcodec copy -acodec copy c:\test2.wmv
```

test2 = test1 (7 sec).

Why? Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to keep the codec, It's not regenerating the GOP structure, which might be longer.

Try with the `-frames` option as suggested in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378702/1244033) or just recode if possible.